# When trying to broadcast via MPI, my broadcast doesn't seem to actually work

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to use MPI to broadcast an array to nodes 1 and 2 from node 0. The array has values in it, however, I cannot seem to successfully broadcast the array despite trying a few different things based on suggestions found here and elsewhere on the net. When I run this, which asks for a file name within the same directory we're running the code from (that file is guaranteed to contain only integers, 1-per-line) I end up with a "Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle", and it happens around my MPI_Bcast(M, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) line, but I can't seem to pinpoint or correct the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int fuelCalc(int array[], int elementCount, int myrank, int worldsize){
    int fuelSum = 0;
    int addlFuelReq = 0;    
    printf("Rank %d has array[0] value %d\n", myrank, array[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++){
        if( (i % worldsize) == myrank){
            usleep(1000000);
            addlFuelReq = (array[i]/4) - 3;
            if(addlFuelReq < 1){addlFuelReq = 1;}
            fuelSum += addlFuelReq;
        }
    }

    return fuelSum;
}

int main(){
    int i = 0, N = 0;
    char fuelFile[30];
    char comp;
    int totalFuel;
    int myrank, worldsize;
    FILE *file;
    int mysum;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldsize);

    if(myrank == 0){

        printf("What file should be used?\n");
        scanf("%s", fuelFile);

        file = fopen(fuelFile, "r");

        if(file == NULL){
            printf("The file entered does not exist.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        for(comp = getc(file); comp!=EOF;comp=getc(file)){
            if(comp == '\n'){
                N = N+1;
            }
        }
    printf("# of Lines: %d\n", N);
}
MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("rank %d has N value %d\n", myrank, N);

int M[N];

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

for( i=0; i<N; i++){
    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &M[i]);
}
if(myrank==0){printf("M[0] = %d\n", M[0]);}

if(myrank==0){printf("Successfully scanned file in to M\n");}
MPI_Bcast(M, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Rank %d has M[0] of %d\n", myrank, M[0]);
mysum = fuelCalc(M, N, myrank, worldsize);
if(myrank==0){printf("Successfully sent M, N, myrank, worldsize to other nodes\n");}
MPI_Reduce(&mysum, &totalFuel,1,MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(myrank==0){printf("Successfully reduced stuff\n");}
if(myrank == 0){
    totalFuel = (totalFuel+((totalFuel/100)*10));
    printf("Total fuel required: %d\n", totalFuel);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

}

Comment: please trim your code down to a [mcve] and hardcode as many values as possible. Then post your `mpirun` command line and any additional values and/or files you are using.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you only open the file on rank 0 so the call to "fseek" will fail on all other processes as the file pointers will be invalid.